# Count members of a record type

Tags: f#

Lets say I have the following type:

```
type BinaryOp =
    { Lhs: int
      Rhs: int
      Destination: int }
```

Is there a F# way of counting the members of that record, i.e. `countMembers<BinaryOp> = 3`? I know I could use `System.Reflection` but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do this without relying on the .NET reflection mechanism. However, the core F# library provides a convenient API on top of the .NET reflection for working with F# types. You can implement `countMembers` using the F# reflection API like this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let countMembers<'T> = 
  FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<'T>).Length
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this, or why you want to avoid reflection - maybe there is a completely diferent design for what you actually want to achieve - but if you need to count the number of fields in a record, this is the best way.

Comment: Thought so. I'm writing a little interpreter and I need to determine by how much I have to increase the instruction pointer. Each instruction is represented by a record type, e.g. `100, 1, 2, 8`, `100` is the op code that determines which record type will be used and `1, 2, 8` are the three operands of `BinaryOp`.

Comment: Regarding why I don't want to use reflection: because it's a runtime operation. There is no reason why my scenario should be evaluated at runtime. This only adds more code that could potentially fail.

Comment: @Timo - Hmm, Your use case sounds completely reasonable to me! I don't think there is a better way of doing that and I can see how doing this at compile-time would make sense. (Though if F# had a mechanism that would let you do this at compile-time, it would probably need to be fairly complex, introducing another area of possible failures, so I feel the reflection here is not too bad!)